# Using url in Django Templates

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-urls

I have the following django 1.9 endpoint:

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/members/(?P<status>active|deactivated)?$',
    gym.GymUserListView.as_view(),
    name='user-list')
```

Using the above, a valid url would be like like `/1/members/active` or `/1/members/deactivated`

I am trying use the `url` in one of my templates like:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning">
  <a href="{% url 'user-list' pk=gym.id status='deactivated' %}"/>View Inactive</a>
</button>
```

This throws the following error:

```
django.core.urlresolvers.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'user-list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': 1, 'status': 'deactivated'}' not found.
0 pattern(s) tried: [ ]
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: `name='user-list'` vs  `url 'user_list'` dash and underline

Comment: @BearBrown, sorry that was a typo on the question, question updated

Comment: Can you post your view?

Comment: From the looks of the error message, I doubt it is this line throwing an error but rather another one before this, where you're passing them as args (not kwargs as here) and `'active'` has quotes (without quotes should throw an error unless there is a context variable called active)

Comment: @ResleyRodrigues, this is thrown when I pass them as `kwargs` `django.core.urlresolvers.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'user-list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': 1, 'status': 'deactivated'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: [
]`

Comment: Perhaps you need to include the namespace, for example `{% url 'users:user-list' pk=gym.id status='deactivated'  %}`

Comment: That's it @Alasdair, it was a namespace issue. Sorted out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have forgotten to include the namespace. The URL tag should be something like:

```
{% url 'users:user-list' pk=gym.id status='deactivated' %}
```

Answer (score 2):

This could be a few things.

- Double check the syntax for that regex (I have not done so). Maybe remove the *or* pattern for the status parameter and replace it with something generic for now to eliminate that as a potential cause.
- You can also try removing the second param entirely and see if you can get the URL generated by pk only - this will tell you for sure if the issue lies with the pattern or the configuration of your urls
- Depending on your app layout, you may need to use the namespace in your templatetag: `{% url 'myapp:user-list' pk=gym.id status='deactivated' %}`
- Is the app where the `urls.py` is for this case in your `INSTALLED_APPS`?